# VB.NET - ASP.NET - Incorrect Username/Password (Validation)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, error-handling, label

Can anyone tell me from the code what's wrong in the code?

The lbl text should show "Incorrect Username/Password" if the Username and Password do not match.

Code:

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\PetLandia\App_Data\db.mdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] where Username=? and Password=?", conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLogin.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)




        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text)) Or (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text)) Then

            lblLoginError.Text = "One or more fields are empty. Please fill in all the fields"
            lblLoginError.Visible = True

        Else

            conn.Open()
            Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            Try

                If read.HasRows Then

                    While read.Read()

                        If txtLogin.Text = read.Item("username").ToString And txtPassword.Text = read.Item("password").ToString Then


                            Dim tUsername As String = read.Item("Username").ToString

                            Session("Username") = tUsername
                            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")


                        End If
                    End While
                End If

                read.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex.Message())
                lblLoginError.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password."
                lblLoginError.Visible = True

            Finally
                conn.Close()
            End Try


        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: OFF Topic but, stuff to consider about your code: **1.** always `dispose` your objects. **2.** never redirect before close the open connections to the database. **3.** always put database code in a method of it's own, and if you can, in it's own layer. **IN Topic** whats the value of `ex.Message()`?

Comment: In addition to balexandre, 1. Don't roll your own security. 2. Don't store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. This code is without `Try` `Catch` block.

```
    Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

         If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text)) Or (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text)) Then
            lblLoginError.Text = "One or more fields are empty. Please fill in all the fields"
            lblLoginError.Visible = True

         Else
            Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\PetLandia\App_Data\db.mdb")
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] where Username=? and Password=?", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLogin.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)
            conn.Open()
            Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()     
                    If read.HasRows Then
                       read.Read()
                       Session("Username") = read.Item("Username").ToString
                       read.Close()
                       conn.Close() 'Close connection before Redirecting.
                       Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")    
                    Else
                      read.Close()
                      conn.Close()
                      lblLoginError.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password."
                      lblLoginError.Visible = True

                    End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: I meant as in "One or more fields are empty. Please fill in all the fields". Whatever I do, it still shows that one.

Comment: lblLoginError.Visible = false;
try putting this in your page_load (if you haven't already)

Comment: @Jane Doe: you are right `lblLoginError.Visible = False` at page load. I think @Brian should has done that.

Comment: What do you mean it was already `lblLoginError.Visible = False` at page load or not?

Comment: I set it visible to be false from the web developer's 2010 properties bar of the label

Comment: If you still getting this error you may have caching in your browser please clear it then try and use my updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `catch` write an `Else` to the if statements

Comment: I marked your answer as useful before you changed it to say the inner If statement. ITYM the If statement which checks read.HasRows: it won't have rows if there were no matching entries.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeh, you would have to check both. Thats why I changed it to "the if statements"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return the username and password from the database as you have them already. You just need to count the matching entries. This greatly simplifies it. Also, as jams showed, it's better to do the test for values in the username and password fields before doing anything to do with the database:

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text)) OrElse (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text)) Then

    lblLoginError.Text = "One or more fields are empty. Please fill in all the fields"
    lblLoginError.Visible = True

Else

    Dim ok As Integer = 0

    Using conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\PetLandia\App_Data\db.mdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] where Username=? and Password=?", conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLogin.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)

        conn.Open()
        ok = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        conn.Close()
    End Using

    If ok = 0 Then
        ' credentials incorrect
    Else
        ' credentials correct
    End If

End If
```

Comment: same problem as with what jams posted. i just replaced the label stuff with the incorrect and redirect with the correct

Comment: @Brian Then txtLogin.Text or txtPassword.Text are null or empty. Are those controls generated at run-time?

Comment: No, when the button is clicked I guess

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct names for those controls? If you put Option Strict On at the top of the code file, it might point out some errors (or it might not, but it's a Good Idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written it,  "Incorrect Username/Password" will only show if an exception is thrown.

if you want to use the code as you've written it, add an ELSE:

```
If txtLogin.Text = read.Item("username").ToString And txtPassword.Text = read.Item("password").ToString Then


                        Dim tUsername As String = read.Item("Username").ToString

                        Session("Username") = tUsername
                        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
else
throw new exception("Incorrect Username/Password")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You decided to roll your own security which led to ...
2. You appear to be storing passwords in plain text which is a huge security hole and potential source of liability.
3. `If read.HasRows` will be false if the passed username and password do not exist in the database. I.e., it will not throw an exception, it will simply return no rows.
4. You did not call `Dispose` on the disposable objects.
5. It would be faster to simply call `ExecuteScalar` with `Select Count(*)` to see if the result is greater than zero.

---

```
Dim authenticationFailed As Boolean = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text) _ 
    OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text)

If Not authenticationFailed Then
    Dim connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0..."
    Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        Const sql As String = "Select Count(*) From [User] Where Username=? and Password=?"
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLogin.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)

            Try
                Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Catch generatedExceptionName As SqlException
                authenticationFailed = True
            End Try

            authenticationFailed = authenticationFailed _ 
                OrElse Convert.ToInt32(result) <> 1

            If Not authenticationFailed Then
                Session("Username") = txtLogin.Text
            End If
        End Using

        conn.Close()
    End Using
End If

If authenticationFailed Then
    lblLoginError.Text = "Incorrect username and password"
    lblLoginError.Visible = True
End If
```